# Verifying Isomorphism between finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

On page 587 in Dummit and Foote, we are given that $f_1(x)=x^4+x^3+1$ and $f_2(x)=x^4+x+1$ are two irreducible quartics over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

The authors then claim that a "simple calculation" verifies that $\alpha (x)=x^3+x^2$ is a root of $f_2(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_{16}=\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^4+x^3+1)$, and we may use this fact to verify that $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^4+x+1)\cong\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^4+x^3+1)$ with $x\mapsto x^3+x^2$.

However, I am having difficulty verifying this calculation. We have that $f_2(\alpha(x))=(x^3+x^2)^4+(x^3+x^2)+1=x^{12}+x^8+x^3+x^2+1$, yet I don't see why this should equal $0$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^4+x^3+1)$. I know that I will have to use the fact that $x^4+x^3+1=0$ in this field, but I'm not sure how. What am I missing?

Comment: The notation $\alpha(x) = x^3 + x^2$ is a bit weird: $\alpha$ is not a polynomial over some field, but an element of the field. It should just be $\alpha = x^3 + x^2$, where the $x$'s really mean the residue class $\bar x$ of $x$ in ${\mathbb F}_2[x]/(x^4+x^3+1)$.

Comment: You can also use the fact that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are reciprocals of each other. So if $\alpha$ is a root of one $1/\alpha$ is a root of the other. Note: $x(x^2+x^3)\equiv1\pmod{x^4+x^3+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is easy. We have
$$
x^{12}+x^8+x^3+x^2+1=
(x^8 + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + 1)(x^4 + x^3 + 1)=0
$$
because $x^4+x^3+1=0$.